# Query Multiple Filters, one with Meta

Tags: filters, query

I am trying to write a Buddypress Query (similar to WP Query).

(1) It must pull all activity entries from a specific user id; regardless of meta mentioned in number 2.
(2) It must also pull activity entries marked with a certain meta value, regardless of the user who created.

Here is my current code for activity arguments:

```
    $activity_args = [
        'per_page' => 5,
        'show_hidden' => true,
        'filter_query' => [ 
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'relation' => 'AND',
                [
                    'column' => 'user_id',
                    'value' => $user,
                    'compare' => '='
                ],
                [
                    'column' => 'component',
                    'value' => 'groups',
                    'compare' => '='
                ],
                [
                    'column' => 'type',
                    'value' => 'activity_update',
                    'compare' => '='
                ],
                [
                    'column' => 'item_id',
                    'value' => $group_id,
                    'compare' => '='
                ]
            ]
        ],
        //'meta_query' => [ [
            //'key' => 'share_guardian',
            //'value' => 'true',
            //'compare' => '='
        //] ]
    ];
```

If I comment out the meta query, number 1 is satisfied.
If I comment out the filter query, number 2 is satisfied.

How do I combine them into a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I muddled around until I found what I feel is the best solution. Please feel free to offer any constructive criticism. I concluded this was not possible with a single query, so I broke it into two queries.

The basic idea is to get all items matching each query, loop them to build an array of id's, then perform a third query from just the id's. While this is probably not the most performant solution; it does give back what I need, in the correct order, maintains pagination, etc.

First query gets all activity entries of a specific user (from a specific group in my case):

```
$firstQueryArgs = [
    'show_hidden' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'filter' => [
        'user_id' => $user,
        'object' => 'groups',
        'action' => 'activity_update',
        'primary_id' => $group_id
    ]
];
```

Second query gets all activity items with a specific meta value:

```
$secondQueryArgs = [
    'show_hidden' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'filter' => [
        'object' => 'groups',
        'action' => 'activity_update',
        'primary_id' => $group_id
    ],
    'meta_query' => [ [
        'key' => 'share_guardian',
        'value' => 'true',
        'compare' => '='
    ] ]
];
```

Now, perform the queries, loop the results, and build an array of id's:

```
// Get queries
$firstQuery = bp_activity_get( $firstQueryArgs );
$secondQuery = bp_activity_get( $secondQueryArgs );

// Loop each query and set ids
$ids = [];

foreach( $firstQuery['activities'] as $key => $act ) {

    $ids[] = $act->id;
}
foreach( $secondQuery['activities'] as $key => $act ) {

    $ids[] = $act->id;
}
```

Finally, I can perform the main query:

```
// Perform final query by ids
$finalQueryArgs = [
    'show_hidden' => true,
    'per_page' => 5,
    'in' => $ids
];

$activity = bp_activity_get( $finalQueryArgs );
```

This is working well for my needs.